# Least-square fitting to data (sine function) : what is the error of the derived fit parameters?

Tags: analysis, mathematical-physics, least-squares, data-analysis, mean-square-error

I have a set of data. I want to fit it to a sine function of the form :
\begin{equation}
f(x)=A sin(\omega x+B)+C
\end{equation}
I use the least-square method to find the appropriate fit-parameters which are $A$, $B$ and $C$. In this method, each term of the cost-function has a weight calculated from the error-bar of each point in my dataset.

Now I want to calculate the visibility $V$ for the fitting curve. The visibility is defined by :
\begin{equation}
V=\frac{A}{C}
\end{equation}

I obtain a good value of $V=0.95$, **but now I want to know how to calculate $\Delta V$,** the error of the visibility. To get it, I need to know $\Delta A$ and $\Delta C$.

Do you know how to do it ?

**EDIT :** Some people suggested to post the data, so here is the figure on the link below.
[Figure representing the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYWwe.png)

Basically, each point has a poissonnian error bar $\Delta Y= \sqrt{Y}$. I did the weighted least-square method to obtain my fit-function which is the solid line you can see on this plot (there is two data-set actually, red and blue). The area in red/blue represent standard deviation of the distance in errorbar unit from the datapoints to the fit, multiplied by the poissonian error $\sqrt{Y}$ [I don't know if this is okay, maybe it's false to do like that].

Comment: Basically I need to know how to get the uncertainties on A and C (because $V=A/C$). I will edit my question.

Comment: Would you mind post your example of data. Concret example is useful to evaluate the difficulty of your problem and well understand it.

Comment: Yes I edited my question

Comment: If this is not a school work, I suggest you use a professional tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fitting problem can be equivalently rewritten as fitting function of form:

$$ f(x) = K \sin(\omega x) + L \cos(\omega x) + C $$

And your original $A$ is just $A =\sqrt{K^2+L^2}$

This reduces it to just ordinary least squares problem. We get least squares estimators for $K,L$ from the equation

$$\begin{bmatrix}
           K \\
           L \\
           C
         \end{bmatrix} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^{T}y$$

Where $X$ is matrix formed by values of $\sin(\omega x),\cos(\omega x), 1$ evaluated at consecutive values of $x$ coordinate of your observations and $y$ are values of said observations.

This way you can see that $K,L$ are some linear functions of $y_i$. I'm not sure what Poissonian error bar is but in general finding variance of sum of variables can be done if we know variance of individual variables.

Assuming $y_i$ uncorrelated we get:

$$ {Var}(K) = (1,0,0) . (X^TX)^{-1}X^{T} . Var(y_i)$$

and analog for $L$.

And $C$ is even simpler as it is just the mean value of the observations.

This way we have found $Var(K),Var(L),Var(C)$ assuming these are small enough you can just propagate error in the formula

$$ V = \frac{\sqrt{K^2+L^2}}{C} $$

either by direct computation or using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty) helpful lookup.

Comment: $X$ is called design matrix. Maybe that will help with the coding part.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you !

Comment: Your linear method is not convenient. You use an unknown value of $\omega$ to compute the matrix $X$. With this method one cannot compute the value of $\omega$. In fact the equation $ f(x) = K \sin(\omega x) + L \cos(\omega x) + C $ is not linear with respect to $\omega$. One have to use a more sophisticated method in case of non-linear equation.

Comment: @JJacquelin OP literally said that only the amplitude was unknown implying that $\omega$ was known and fixed. If you want to fit $\omega$ it is a completely different problem. (Indeed a non-linear, and by some measure harder one).

Comment: From the picture uploaded looks like the domain of $x$ is $[0,2\pi)$ so $\omega$ is probably just $1$.

Comment: OK. If $\omega$ is known the difficult part of the job is done. What remains to do is easy.