# Can $a\sin{bx}$ be expressed in matrix form?

Tags: trigonometry, matrix-equations

(I am trying to determine if given a dataset and this function, can it be solve using the Least Squared Error Method.)
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

yes it can, so lets use your assumption that:
$$y=a\sin(bx)$$
however there will be an associated error for each term, namely:
$$r_i=y_i-y(x_i)$$
$$r_i=y_i-a\sin(bx_i)$$
now you simply define your sum:
$$S=\sum r_i^2=\sum\left[y_i-a\sin(bx_i)\right]^2$$
now you want to optimise for $a,b$ such that $S$ is as small as possible, which would mean:
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial a}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial b}=0$$
can you take it from here?

---

$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial a}=-2\sin(bx_i)\left[y_i-a\sin(bx_i)\right]=0$$
$$\therefore y_i\sin(bx_i)-a\sin^2(bx_i)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial b}=-2ax_i\cos(bx_i)\left[y_i-a\sin(bx_i)\right]=0$$
$$\therefore ax_iy_i\cos(bx_i)-a^2x_i\sin(bx_i)\cos(bx_i)=0$$
unfortunately as you can see these two simultaneous equations are hard to solve for $a,b$. Also if it wasn't clear all of the above expressions are summations but I removed the symbols as it can make it look very messy

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm afraid though your explanation is beyond the scope of my understaning. I am trying to determine if I can express the data in terms of this function as Ax=b or Ax=0. To do so I am trying to express the function as a product of two matrices. for example, the function ax+b = y can be express like this: [x 1] x [a \nb] (the second matrix is a of dim 2x1). Can the same be done with asin(bx)? I thought perhaps theres is a trig identity which I am missing. Thanks

Comment: The method you asked for (Least squares) is the one that I have given above, for anything other than a linear function you have to derive the matrix yourself using the method above, I will add to my answer to show you how to get to that step

Comment: Here is also a link to a similar problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3249623/least-square-fitting-to-data-sine-function-what-is-the-error-of-the-derived

Comment: Thanks, I understand the process of what you have kindly showed, though I don't see how I can feed the results into my algorithm,  specifically because I cannot see how I can express x, y and a,b in distinct matrices.

Comment: Yep that is the problem when you have functions like this and two optimised variables as products, often it has to be done numerically. Obviously you can make these slight simplifications: $$\sum y_i-a\sin(bx_i)=0$$ from both which you can solve for $b$ then use this to solve for $a$

Comment: i.e. $$b=\frac{\arcsin\left(\frac{\sum y_i}{a}\right)}{\sum x_i}$$